# Perl - using rsync from perl script

Tags: perl, terminal, command

I'm having trouble writing up a simple perl script so I can sync two folders.
My code is:

```
my $string= "rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music\ \(1\)/ ~/Music/Music/";
`$string`;
```

I also tried just using the line

```
`rsync -va /Dropbox/Music\ \(1\)/ ~/Music/Music/;`
```

Next I tried:

```
my @args=("bash", "-c","rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music\ \(1\)/ ~/Music/Music/");
system(@args);`
```

I get the same error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' each time
```

(yeah, those spaces and parens in the originating folder are a pain, but don't yell at me, I didn't create it....)

Comment: I've attempted to fix the formatting, but in a few places I wasn't 100% sure what it was supposed to look like. Please take a look, and correct anything that needs correction.

Comment: @ruakh Thanks, how do you escape the backslash character, or what was I misssing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the actual shell command you're running is

```
rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music (1)/ ~/Music/Music/
```

because the all the backslashes are swallowed by Perl (since it, like Bash, uses backslash as a quoting/escape character). To avoid this, you need to either use single-quotes:

```
system 'rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music\ \(1\)/ ~/Music/Music/';
```

or else re-escape your backslashes:

```
system "rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music\\ \\(1\\)/ ~/Music/Music/";
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Why (and how) are single and double quotes different in Perl?

Comment: @ImprovedSilence: Re: how they differ: single-quotes don't interpolate variables (so `'$foo'` are `'@foo'` are equivalent to `"\$foo"` and `"\@foo"`, respectively), and they don't support backslash-escapes other than `\'` and `\\ ` (so `'\n'` and `'\x0A'` are equivalent to `"\\n"` and `"\\x0A"`, respectively). Re: why they differ: Various shells, such as Bash, have this feature. As far as I can tell, Perl has never met a language feature it didn't want to steal. :-P

Comment: @ImprovedSilence: By the way, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators for many more related features. For example, `q{...}` and `q"..."` are roughly equivalent to `'...'`, and `qx'...'` is like backquotes but without causing interpolation . . . there's a lot. :-)

Comment: You're even better off using system on a *list* instead of a string, thus defeating the escaping by bypassing the shell. E.g., `system('rsync', '-va', '/home/bob/Dropbox/Music (1)/', '/home/Music/Music/');` (notice that you also lose bash's expansion of `~`

Answer (score 1):

After executing

```
my $string= "rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music\ \(1\)/ ~/Music/Music/";
```

you'll see that `$string` contains

```
rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music (1)/ ~/Music/Music/
```

That's not the command you want to execute. `\` is special in Perl double-quoted string literals (among others). To create the string

```
rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music\ \(1\)/ ~/Music/Music/
```

You need

```
$string = "rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music\\ \\(1\\)/ ~/Music/Music/";
```

Alternatively, use the multi-arg form of [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). Since no shell is involved, you don't have to worry about creating string literals for the shell.

```
my $src = $ENV{HOME}.'/Dropbox/Music (1)/';
my $dst = $ENV{HOME}.'/Music/Music/';
system('rsync', '-va', $src, $dst);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl isn't needed here.

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music\ \(1\)/ ~/Music/Music/
```

Or you could add the following to `~/.bashrc` then log back in:

```
alias music_sync='rsync -va ~/Dropbox/Music\ \(1\)/ ~/Music/Music/'
```